# Symfony 3.4/routing: Urlencoded "/" in the parameter value cause not matching the route

Tags: symfony, routes

So, I will explain the problem and actual question will be if it's a Bug:

```
$routes = new RouteCollection();
$context = new RequestContext('/');
$matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);

$route = new Route('/foo/{name}');
$routes->add('route_name', $route);
$parameters = $matcher->match('/foo/somedata%2Fblax');
```

This gives an exception 'No routes found for "/foo/somedata%2Fblax"'

if remove  %2F (url encoded slash) from the path like:

```
$parameters = $matcher->match('/foo/somedatablax');
```

then everything works fine, $parameters:

```
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'somedatablax' (length=12)
  '_route' => string 'route_name' (length=10)
```

So going further set the url pattern to be `/foo/somedata/{name}`:

```
 $routes = new RouteCollection();
 $context = new RequestContext('/');
 $matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);

 $route = new Route('/foo/somedata/{name}');   
 $routes->add('route_name', $route);
 $parameters = $matcher->match('/foo/somedata%2Fblax');
```

This will return:

```
array (size=2)
  'name' => string 'blax' (length=4)
  '_route' => string 'route_name' (length=10)
```

Which means url encoded slash was treated as a regular slash when matching pattern which seems to be wrong (isn't that one of the reasons why url encoding exists?)

I made some investigation and found why this works that way (not easy to fix though)

To is this a bug or is there any flow in my logic? It clearly looks like a bug but it seems like it is there for a long time now (from the very beginning may be?)

Also there is a kind of solution(which actually is not and it doesn't meant to be a solution for this particular problem but still relevant): [symfony4](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html) and the same for [symfony2](http://symfony2-document.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html).

Comment: To clarify, applying permissive regular expression (`requirements={"token"=".+"}') can only be applied to the very last parameter of the url as stated in the links provided so it's not a universal solution

Answer (score 0):

As default any route parameter match the character "/" although you can use the parameter requirements which sets the regular expression to match what you think it is suitable.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html

```
$routes = new RouteCollection();
$context = new RequestContext('/');
$matcher = new UrlMatcher($routes, $context);

$route = new Route('/foo/{name}', [], ['name'=>'.+']);
$routes->add('route_name', $route);
$parameters = $matcher->match('/foo/somedata%2Fblax');
```

Now it should match your route.

Although you are right. The symfony router does a rawurldecode before matching the route:

**vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Matcher/UrlMatcher.php**

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function match($pathinfo)
    {
        $this->allow = array();

        if ($ret = $this->matchCollection(rawurldecode($pathinfo), $this->routes)) {
            return $ret;
        }
        [...]
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be relevant to my question, am I wrong?

Comment: I've really think it is the answer, but maybe I haven't explained myself right. You are asking why it matches in one case and not in the other isn't it? I've explained that you are right mentioning that it decodes the content and how to make it behave the same in both user cases.

Comment: well even though you edited it to be relevant this is still not a solution. This solution described in the links I provided. And this is not a solution because it will only work correctly for very last parameter of the url, [symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/slash_in_parameter.html) note: 

For example, if the route definition is /share/{path}/{token} and both path and token accept /, then path will contain its contents and the token, and token will be empty.